# Are there any way to add new variables to existing checkpoint by force in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

Assume that there is a deep learning model and a checkpoint with pre-trained weights. What I want to do is to fine-tune the pre-trained model. However, I found that I have to fine-tune the model with a new ADAM optimizer which is not defined in the existing model graph. Since ADAM optimizer itself has some trainable_variables, I have to add those to the existing checkpoint if I want to fine-tune the model based on the checkpoint. Are there any way to add new variables to existing checkpoint by force in tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`tf.compat.v1.train.warm_start`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/train/warm_start) to fine tune your new model with weights from a previously-trained model.

Normally you'd restore variables using `tf.train.Saver` or `tf.train.Checkpoint`. If you use `tf.compat.v1.train.warm_start`, it'll restore the variables that your new model has in common with the old model but it'll leave it up to you to initialize any new variables you've added.